# My app crashes on CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, crash

My app crashes on `CGRectIntersectsRect` and I dont know what to do.
Here is my code :

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame)) 
{
    loseViewController *controller = [[loseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"loseView" bundle:nil];                                        

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];   
    [controller release];
}
```

Comment: `player` or `enemy` might have been deallocated, could you check that ?

Comment: As @Vince says, probably one of those objects has been dealloc'd. Try enabling zombies which will help with determining that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-in-xcode for turning on zombies in Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Vince's comment (I'm not sure why it wasn't an answer!) . . . .

Where does it crash if you do

```
CGRect playerRect = player.frame;
CGRect enemyRect = enemy.frame;
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, enemyRect)) {
```

instead of

```
if(CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,enemy.frame)) {
```

That should tell you which (or both) object has been deallocated.

Comment: Unless there's a bug in `CGRectIntersectsRect`. OK, highly unlikely, but worth checking with either zombies or your code first. I prefer the zombies approach personally as I think (in general) it should always be on during development. That and having a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`!

Comment: Then put a breakpoint on the first line and step through - that should tell you if it's `player` or `enemy` that's been dealloced. If you get to the CGRectIntersectsRect then tell us that the rects are.

Comment: We're should I put the breakpoint and does my code look correct

Comment: That comment tells me you haven't tried what's in my question. Put the breakpoint on the first line of my original answer.